# Cropping circles in an image with imfindcircles

Tags: matlab

I am doing a road sign recognition program in Matlab and I want to recognize circular roadsigns. Therefore I use the matlab function imfindcircles. I would like to crop only the circular roadsigns and to put them in an isolate figure. However, we have other roadsigns on each figure (triangles or squares) but I don't want them. I have no idea how to do this. Here my code :

```
[im_bw,map] = imread('roadsign.JPG'); %image black and white

S = regionprops(im_bw,'Extrema','Centroid','BoundingBox');

[centers, radii] = imfindcircles(im_bw,[12 40]); 

for k = 1:length(S)

   im_cercle = imcrop(im_bw, S(k).BoundingBox); 
   im_cercle = padarray(im_cercle, [20 20]); % put each roadsigns in a small figure

      if radii(k) ~= 0 % Error 

   figure,imshow(im_cercle); title 'Circle spotted'; % Show every circular roadsigns in a figure

      else

   figure('visible','off'),imshow(im_cercle); title 'wrong raodsign';

      end

end
```

I tried some other conditions with centres and radii but when I execute the code, i get dimension errors or sometimes it shows me a shape which is not a circle. I also tried to do a variable that only sets when he finds a circle, but without results. Can you help me please ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: if you can add your image it'll be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What you do you expect the output of `regionprops` to be? It isn't picking out the circles - it's picking out all the "areas" (anything that is a connected area in `im_bw`).  In addition while `imfindcircles` can find circles that overlap with other things, `regionprops` will detect overlapping areas as a single object.

On the other hand, you call `imfindcircles` and then do nothing with the output.

Rather than doing anything with `regionprops`, just use the values of `centers`, `radii` to define a bounding box around each detected circle (optionally with some additional padding), crop that area out of the image and save/display it.